# how to split a list with delimiters in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to split a list with a delimiter ',', but inside a list element there is also the character ',', example:

```
1|[this is first element, this is seconde element, this is (bad, element)]
```

I want to play in a datafame , but this comma in the third element breaks the logic

```
current output :
id |name   |val
1  |Column0|this is first element
1  |Column2|this is seconde element
1  |Column3|this is (bad
1  |Column4|element)


expected output:
id |name   |val
1  |Column0|this is first element
1  |Column1|this is seconde element
1  |Column2|this is (bad, element)

df = df.select("id",f.split("text", ",").alias("text"),f.posexplode_outer(f.split("text", ",")).alias("pos", "val")).drop("val") \    .select("id","text",f.concat(f.lit("Column"),f.col("pos").cast("string")).alias("name"),f.expr("text[pos]").alias("val"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to find the correct pattern for `split` to ignore `,` in between `()`

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
,\s*(?![^()]*\))
```

This regex is finding a comma with an assertion that makes sure comma is not in parentheses. This is done using a negative lookahead that first consumes all matching `(` and `)` and then a `)`. **This assumes parentheses are balanced and unescaped**.

```
# Create data frame
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[(1, "this is first element, this is seconde element, this is (bad, element)")], 
("id", "text"))

# import functions
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

# apply transformation
df1 = df.select("id",f.split("text", ",\s*(?![^()]*\))").alias("text"),f.posexplode_outer(f.split("text", ",\s*(?![^()]*\))")).alias("pos", "val")).drop("val").select("id","text",f.concat(f.lit("Column"),f.col("pos").cast("string")).alias("name"),f.expr("text[pos]").alias("val"))
```

Pass your string in the below Link and It will give you the result

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pS9oV3/3)

Comment: The solution worked perfectly, thanks.

However, I found another pattern that made the logic break, there is a comma in fields without the parentheses, for example:
1|[ this is, a element]